# How can i write the validation for number+string?

Tags: java, android, validation, logic

I am stuck with small problem. I think in the java we can easily write the validation but i want a smart logic.

In my registration page there is a name field.

**Name should be like Rahul0533 but not like 0533rahul..**

For that i wrote the logic for getting first char in that string and check.I think it is huge. so please help how can i validate.

Here in my name field and my name should not start with special characters and numbers. Remaining all is accepted.

Comment: Use [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)!

Comment: have u know regular expression in java

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Hey sorry. I am from electrical. I don't know. I will learn and try.

Comment: I Think regular expressions are quite overkill for this simple check (compiling the pattern etc.). "Character.isLetter(name.charAt(0))" should be enough.

Comment: @Udo that's why the `Pattern` should always be compiled as `static final`.

Comment: Yes of course. But evaluating the pattern also requires more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use regex for validation

```
String name = "client name";
String patternString = ""; // your regexp
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
```

regex basic syntax
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this in your submit function.

```
private void submit(EditText text) {
    String userName = text.getText().toString();
    if(userName.length() == 0) {
        //Error, user name cannot be empty
    }
    else if(!Character.isLetter(userName.charAt(0))) {
        //Error, the first char  can only be a letter
    }
    else {
        //do registration
    }
}
```